# Saving Kotlin ByteArray into Realm

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I want to save bitmap into Realm DB. I converted bitmap into ByteArray and created Realm model class:

```
    @RealmClass
    open class PictureModel : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = ""
    var picture : ByteArray = byteArrayOf()
    }
```

but during compilation it gives me an error:

> w: warning: Unclosed files for the types; these types will not undergo annotation processing

Realm is supposed to support java `byte[]` but what about Kotlin `ByteArray` or `Array<Byte>`

Comment: `byteArrayOf()` is Java equivalent of `byte[]`. Try makring `picture` with `@Required`

Comment: `@Required` doesn't help

Comment: For anyone who is interested as a workaround I changed picture type to `String` and before saving it I converted `ByteArray` to `String`: `val pictureAsString = pictureAsByteArray.toString(charset("ISO-8859-1"))`. After fetching it from db I convert it back to `ByteArray` => `picture.toByteArray(charset("ISO-8859-1"))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
open class Test : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
     var id: String? = null
    var picture: ByteArray? = null
}
```